# Insulation for magnetic fields

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, experimental-technique, conductors

How can I insulate conductors independently one off the other, where they pass through a magnetic field? Are there a techniques or alloys? There is a issue how to insulate copper wire where current flows and that copper wire - wire's are in strong magnetic field. Additionally, insulators must isolate every wire independently. That's coil with 100 or more turns.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67728/.

Comment: Yes, I have read this article but, there is a issue how to insulate copper wire where current flows and that copper wire's are in strong magnetic field. Additionally insulators must isolate every wire independently. That's coil with 100 turns...

Comment: What is the use of that "insulation" you are looking for?

Comment: Better controlled magnetic field that passing throughout the wire, it's not same if field passes throughout 100 or 1000 turns, but could be if there would be insulator where induction must pass in one directions throughout one wire with same length.